# Using Makefiles In Nested Directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

A project that I am working on deals with multiple architectures. The code is divided into architecture specific and general modules (which can be shared between the architectures).

I am planning to organize the code as below

```
TOP
|
|---- Makefile
|
|---- src (arch independent)
|---- inc (arch independent)
|
|----arch1 (arch specific)
     |---- src 
     |---- inc 
     |---- Makefile
|----arch2 (arch specific)
     |---- src
     |---- src
     |---- Makefile
```

The arch specific project would be compiled by the Makefile within the arch directory. This makefile includes the Makefile at the TOP level.

The idea was that in the arch specific makefile will have all the src code from within the arch directory and the top level Makefile defines a variable which is simply the path of the TOP level directory, so that the arch specific Makefile can include code from the src folder in the top level.

However, when including the top level Makefile, the defined path variable (through shell pwd command) is evaluuated at the arch specific directory level.

How can I solve this? Is their a better way of doing this?

Right now it's a 2 level structure. But in future I plan top make it multi level with innermost level being arch specific and the layers become more and more general as one moves out to the top level.

Comment: Take a look at [Multi-Architecture Builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/). It's quite old but I think it is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

What is your top-level makefile doing? - I mean, can you run make on it standalone? If not then all you really appear to gain from it is the list of source files and header locations - it would be easier to just specify those in a `common_make.mk` or somthing which only contains:

```
SOURCES += ../src/test1.c
SOURCES += ../src/test2.c
SOURCES += ../src/test3.c
INC += ../inc
```

then both of your lower level file include this very basic makefile "snippet" and you don't have to worry about the paths.

Usually I am putting common elements into separate config controlled repos and I have my projects the other way around:

```
arch1/
   |--src
   |--inc
   |--common (repo)
       |--inc
       |--src 

arch2/
   |--src
   |--inc
   |--common (repo)
       |--inc
       |--src
```

So here I  have two separate repo's with a shared sub-repo. If you wanted to tie the two archx projects together you can add those to into a super-repo with it's own makefile that just does:

```
make -C arch1
make -C arch2
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you

### Common makefile template for archX/ directories

```
# ./Makefile.template
ARCH_DIR        := $(PWD)
TOP_DIR         := $(ARCH_DIR)/..
BUILD_DIR       := $(TOP_DIR)/build

# non-architecture specific source code
NOARCH_SRC_DIR  := $(TOP_DIR)/src
NOARCH_INC_DIR  := $(TOP_DIR)/inc

# non-architecture specific source code
ARCH_SRC_DIR    := $(ARCH_DIR)/src
ARCH_INC_DIR    := $(ARCH_DIR)/inc

# other stuff...
CFLAGS          := -I$(ARCH_INC_DIR) -I$(NOARCH_INC_DIR)

# directory specific variables, e.g. XXX_SRCS
include $(NOARCH_SRC_DIR)/Makefile.include
include $(ARCH_SRC_DIR)/Makefile.include

# generate object file lists
NOARCH_OBJS     := $(NOARCH_SRCS:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
ARCH_OBJS       := $(ARCH_SRCS:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

# add paths to source files
NOARCH_SRCS     := $(addprefix $(NOARCH_SRC_DIR)/, $(NOARCH_SRC_DIR))
ARCH_SRCS       := $(addprefix $(ARCH_SRC_DIR)/,   $(ARCH_SRC_DIR))

# target-specific pattern rules for C files
$(NOARCH_OBJS): %.o: $(NOARCH_SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(ARCH_OBJS): %.o: $(ARCH_SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

... and so ...
```

### ArchX/ directory makefile

```
# archX/Makefile
# common stuff
include $(PWD)/../Makefile.template

# arch specific targets follow here...
```

Now you can already run the build using

```sh
 $ make -C arch1
```

### Top-level directory Makefile

```
 # ./Makefile
 ifndef ARCH
 $(error you must specifiy ARCH=)
 endif

 # forward all targets to arch directory
 %:
      $(MAKE) -C $(ARCH) $(MAKECMDGOAL)
```

Now you can run the build using

```sh
 $ make ARCH=arch1
```

Personally I would not write the top-level makefile at all and use only the former approach.

---

IMHO you should avoid things like `$(shell)`. But maybe that is just my personal view, take it with a grain of salt...

Comment: Check out: [Recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) - that's what `$(MAKE) -C` does. In short, it breaks parallel build; the recommendation is to `include` all the child makefiles and let `make` figure out the optimal build order.

Comment: That document ignores [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). Based on my extensive 20+ years experience in large SW build systems, "Single makefile considered harmful" is the more appropriate statement.

Comment: It definitely doesn't ignore Amdahl's law when your build is barely using 2 cores on a 16-core system. The general suitability of `make` for a large system builds is questionable, though.

Comment: @VictorSergienko well, then your experience differs from mine. Let's leave it at that.